# How can I restrict access from external IP's for a ngnix location

Tags: nginx

I want to restrict access to an ngnix location from external IP's. I add the following configuration to the ngnix config file, but I am not sure if it is the right way to do so. Is there any better alternatives for restricting the external IP's to access a location?

```
map $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for $remote_ip {
    default     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    ""          $http_x_real_ip;
}
map $remote_ip $isinternal {
    ~^127\.                                             1;
    ~^10\.                                              1;
    ~(^172\.1[6-9]\.)|(^172\.2[0-9]\.)|(^172\.3[0-1]\.) 1;
    ~^192\.168\.                                        1;
    default                                             0;
}

...

location /app/sniper {
    if ($isinternal != 1) { return 403; }
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use nginx [geo](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) module for IP address maps. Your configuration would be like this with it:

```
geo $internal {
    default        0;
    127.0.0.0/8    1;
    10.0.0.0/8     1;
    172.16.0.0/20  1;
    192.168.0.0/24 1;
}

location /app/sniper {
    if ($internal != 1) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tero thanks for the response, do you have any comments for getting the real IP?  Is there a better way to get the real IP where I search http_x_real_ip and _x_forwarded_for?

Comment: If you are behind a proxy, I would use https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html to get the IP address.